# What is the per user rate limit for Google Street View Image API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I am working on a web application that uses Google's Street View Image API to load many street view images (with JavaScript). While I can load a good number, it seems to cut me off and return 403 errors if I exceed some rate (I am not exceeding the total allocation of 1000).

I have continually tried to slow down the rate at which I download the images, but I cannot find a sweet spot at which the API will let me download continuously at that rate. I have checked the [documentation](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/) and it does not give a description of the rate.

Also, assuming such a rate does exist, is this calculated on a per-user (per-IP) basis or from my API key?

Answer (score 2):

You noticed that the problems start at 10requests/second.

There is a limit defined for [business-users](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/business/faq.html#usage_limits):
**All web services: Rate limit of 10 requests per second.**

Let's assume that you don't get lower rates than free users when you pay for a service.

I guess this limit is only defined for business-users, because it's also a guarantee for 10 available requests per second.

Comment: Good find, thank you.  For many services it seems to be variable in Google's API Console, but they don't have the Street View API there yet.  I believe my IP or API is currently blocked for placing too many requests.  I will try tomorrow with a rate of 5 requests/second and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not document the exact rate, but it is spread out over the day. The rate is calculated on a per IP address basis.

Have you thought of using the JavaScript API? Perhaps it wouldn't work for you, but it is not quota'd in the same way.

Comment: As I wrote below, it appears they rate limit at a finer grained limit than per day.  If I am making 10 requests/second it starts serving the 403 errors.  Also, the only official API to access Street View images is that list; the JS API does not include support for this.  There is [this](http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/15/google-streetview-static-api/) API, which is used internally by Google Maps, but using this breaks the API and I do not want to have my account/website banned.

Comment: Right, I wasn't sure if you needed direct access to the image, if you do than this is your only option. Google does not document the rate limit, however the limit is by IP address only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and changed the rate to 1 image every 1.5 seconds and still get blocked images after minutes of use.

I changed the user rate via the API console and used my API Key on the URL but that didn't work

I've now moved to interactive streetview Images as that limit doesn't get hit

Comment: If I am not mistaken (unless the console was very recently updated) it does not yet contain the API for static Streetview images.  Which API did you rate limit?  Also, what interactive Streetview image API are you referring to?

Comment: your right there isn't a limit for static streetview image so I rate limited it using javascript setTimeout() function.  I thought changing the limit on "Google Maps API v3" would change this but it didn't. The interactive streetview image API I'm talking about is just the Google Maps API v3 Streetview in a DIV container